# Maintaing multiple HttpRequests through a daemon thread in Mule

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, mule

I have a scenario that requires a synchronous web service to create a response after making a call to an asynchronous service (with a correlation ID to identify this event at a later time). The asynchronous service would place the results in a cache. And my web service needs to setup an active poller/listener to wait for an event with the same correlation id to be inserted in the cache. Once the record is available, the web service can create a response object and send it over to client.

Now, the async process could take a long time which would result in idling the main thread of my web service.
The web service is being developed as a mule workflow, and the exact scenario is shown below:

```
                   |→ async service → update cache → end //Async thread
Client--> myWebSvc |
                   |→ setup cache listener → onEvent() → respond to Client //Main thread
```

Is there a way in mule that could help me maintain a map of such HttpRequests and maintain them in a daemon thread? This would help take up new requests while waiting on response for old ones.

I have started looking at Java NIO but am unable to think of ways to integrate it with the Mule workflow. Is there a solution within mule that can help me free up the main thread and store the HttpRequest object in a map to be called upon later?

Just a few more details:
The web service is implemented in java. The mule workflow looks like this:

```
                                             |→ async subflow to invoke async process
HTTP Request → CXF component → Java component|
                                             |→ (sub flow) Java component to listen to events
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some basic research and guidance from Mule folks, I found that mule has incorporated the non-blocking threads implementation. On the main flow, the "Optional Processing Strategy" can be set to achieve this.

By using this strategy, the HTTP listener thread will pass the received payload to the next component in the flow and the thread is returned to a flow thread pool. Once the response is received, the event thread needs to be obtained from the thread pool once more.

```
<flow name="sample-flow" processingStrategy="non-blocking">
    <http:listener config-ref="http-listener-configuration"
                   path="samplews" doc:name="http-ws-endpoint" allowedMethods="GET,POST"/>
    <logger message="Received payload: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO"
            doc:name="Payload Received"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" port="myAPI" service="myAPI"
                       serviceClass="org.sample.wshandler.SomeClass" soapVersion="1.2" doc:name="cxf-tradefeed-api">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="logger"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="logger"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>
    <flow-ref name="wsImpl-sub-flow" doc:name="wsImpl-sub-flow"/>
</flow>
```

More details are provided at the MuleSoft documentation: [Mule Non-Blocking](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/flow-processing-strategies#non-blocking-processing-strategy)